# Return remainder of a variable if started with given character

Tags: php

If the value of a variable (i.e. `$var="^hello`";) starts with a given character (i.e. `^`), how could I return the remainder of that variable (i.e. `hello`), and return`FALSE` (or `NULL` or `0` if easier) if it doesn't start with the given character?  Note that there is no guarantee that the variable will be a string.  I tried the following, but it results in errors if the value is NULL.

```
$var='^hello'; //Works
$var=123; //Works
$var=NULL; //Doesn't work
echo ($var[0]=='^')?substr($var,1):false;
echo($new);
```

Comment: If it is not a string, convert it?

Comment: `it results in errors`? What errors? This shouldn't give any errors at all, as it's perfectly valid PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker.  I am sorry.  The error I am getting is `Uninitialized string offset: 0`.  It appears to be unrelated.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't an integer that causes a problem, it is NULL!  Of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done actually works, but when you `echo` `false`, nothing will appear on the screen, so just wrap `false` with double quotes to display `"false"` on the screen

```
$var='^hello'; //Works
$var=123; //Works
echo ($var[0]=='^')?substr($var,1):"false"; // Add double quotes to false
```

**[Live demo](http://ideone.com/M0QYOa)**

EDIT.  Note that this will not work if $var is set to NULL.  To prevent an error, just change `($var[0]=='^')` to `($var && $var[0]=='^')`

Answer (score 0):

test this

```
$var="^hello";
if(substr($var,1,1)=="^")
    echo substr($var,1,strlen($var));
else
    echo "0";
```